# Show difference between two subqueries as additional column in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with the main data and a second table with historical values.

Table `stocks`

```
+----------+-------+-----------+
| stock_id | symbol| name      |    
+----------+-------+-----------+    
|        1 |  AAPL | Apple     |
|        2 |  GOOG | Google    |
|        3 |  MSFT | Microsoft |
+----------+-------+-----------+
```

Table `prices`

```
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| stock_id | price | date                |    
+----------+-------+---------------------+    
|        1 |  0.05 | 2015-02-24 01:00:00 |
|        2 |  2.20 | 2015-02-24 01:00:00 |
|        1 |  0.50 | 2015-02-23 23:00:00 |
|        2 |  1.90 | 2015-02-23 23:00:00 | 
|        3 |  2.10 | 2015-02-23 23:00:00 |
|        1 |  1.00 | 2015-02-23 19:00:00 |
|        2 |  1.00 | 2015-02-23 19:00:00 | 
+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

I need a query that returns:

```
+----------+-------+-----------+-------+
| stock_id | symbol| name      | diff  |  
+----------+-------+-----------+-------+    
|        1 |  AAPL | Apple     | -0.45 |
|        2 |  GOOG | Google    | 0.30  |
|        3 |  MSFT | Microsoft | NULL  |
+----------+-------+-----------+-------+
```

Where diff is the result of subtracting from the newest price of a stock the previous price.
If one or less prices are present for a particular stock I should get NULL.

I have the following queries that return the last price and the previous price but I don't know how to join everything

```
/* last */
SELECT price 
FROM prices
WHERE stock_id = '1'
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 1

/* previous */
SELECT price 
FROM prices
WHERE stock_id = '1'
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 1,1
```

Using MySQL 5.5

Comment: do you want only the last increment? or do you want all the increments?

Comment: @Barranka only the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the expected result set:

```
SELECT stock_id, symbol, name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN price END) - 
       SUM(CASE WHEN row_number = 2 THEN price END) AS diff
FROM (
   SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @stock=stock_id THEN @row_number+1 
                            ELSE 1 
                       END AS row_number,
          @stock:=stock_id AS stock_id,
          price, date, symbol, name
   FROM (SELECT p.stock_id, s.symbol, s.name, p.price, p.date
         FROM prices AS p
         INNER JOIN stocks AS s ON p.stock_id = s.stock_id
         ORDER BY stock_id, date DESC) AS t
   ) u
GROUP BY u.stock_id
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08d982/1)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
SELECT s1.symbol,
       s1.name,
       COALESCE ((SELECT price 
                    FROM prices p1
                   WHERE p1.stock_id = s1.stock_id
                   ORDER BY dateTime DESC 
                   LIMIT 1), 0) -
       COALESCE ((SELECT price       
                    FROM prices p2
                   WHERE p2.stock_id = s1.stock_id
                   ORDER BY dateTime DESC 
                   LIMIT 1,1), 0) AS diff
  FROM stocks s1;
```

Comment: I'm surprised when OPs accept answers that are different from what they seem to be asking for.

Comment: @Trinimon That works to get the difference in stock price, but it doesn't return the table I expect nor the NULL value on inexisting prices.

Comment: Ok, I see - the example is really helpful. I made an update. It's basically the same idea, however, `stocks` is now used as the driving table.

Comment: @Trinimon that works changing the 0 in the COALESCE with NULL. Thanks.

Comment: If null is fine for you, you could remove the COALESCE function.